# VIsual Studio 2013 - Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I just got a Windows 8 PC and installed Visual Studio 2013 Pro and Visual Studio 2013 Express. Unfortunately I am not able to create Javascript projects to develop apps for tablets. Do I need to install something more?
Regards,

Comment: Strange.. I am not sure about this
Is it fine for C# & other templates.?

Comment: There is written, that it is also possible and screenshots. But somehow it doesn't apper in Visual Studio 2013... Btw there are also samples of JS Code ))

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on a machine that only had Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows (not desktop) installed. Going to Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs and running a repair on VS fixed it - the New Project dialog now lists JavaScript Store App templates.

Possibly I should mark my question as a dup and redirect here?

Comment: +1 This worked for me using Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows with Update 3. Thank you!

Comment: I would also like to confirm this solution working. Initial install of VS 2013 express didn't have the Javascript templates but then I did the repair as mentioned in above answer and restarted the PC, then all Javascript App templates were there. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript templates are not installed by default. If you open the **New Project** dialog, you'll see a link **Click here to go online and find templates**. Click this link and you'll see all the other templates you can install. The JavaScript ones are in the Samples section. I assume that by tablet apps you mean Windows Store apps, so open that section and take your pick.

BTW, this is for Visual Studio 2013 Pro, I haven't got the Express version installed so I don't know if it works there.

Comment: But I've seen screen-shots from Visual Studio where there was JavaScript below Templates right beside VB and C#. Probably it was VS 2012 but I wonder why they hide it in VS 2013. Isn't JavaScript a 1st class citizen for Windows 8 anymore?

Comment: I found the page with the screen-shot and it is supposed to be VS 2013 Express: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To develop 'JavaScript - Windows Store applications'  Visual Studio Express 2012 *for Windows 8* and  Windows 8 must be installed.

However, if all JavaScript templates are missing try installing the following from the from Microsoft site.

- "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 5"; and
- "Visual Studio 2013 Extensions for the Windows Library for JavaScript"

Once these are installed you may be prompted to also install 'Multi-Device Hybrid App Tools' from within Visual Studio when clicking on a JavaScript template.